# My login page always redirects to authentication failed url

Tags: java, spring-security

```
<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/secure/denied" >

            <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/login*" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome/**" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/admin*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/common*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

-->

```
    <security:form-login
                            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/secure/login.html" 
            authentication-failure-url="/secure/login.html?authfailed=true" 
            default-target-url="/welcome/add.html"
                            always-use-default-target="true"

                            />

    <security:logout 
            invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/secure/login.html" 
            logout-url="/secure/logout.html"/>

</security:http>

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
                <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
<beans:bean  class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

<!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
<beans:bean  id="customUserDetailsService" class="service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>
```

## debug message:

even my debug shows this: Successfully authenticated. Security context contains: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@55d3f463: Principal: TDOSUNMu; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER

Answer (score 0):

`default-target-url="/welcome/add.html"` will redirect you to page `add.html` in case of a successful login.

Or you may use the `@RequestMapping`annotation to do some logic before proceding to the page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome/add.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(ModelMap model) {
    // TODO logic ...
    return "/home.html";
}
```